# Crystal report display a text

Tags: excel, crystal-reports

In Crystal report, if I print two pages I want to display them on the first page as "continued on next page". If only one page it should not show "continued on next page". How can I write the code for this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Create this formula:

```
IF PageNumber < TotalPageCount Then "Continued on Next Page..." else ""
```

Comment: I have some transactions where I have given dashed lines to display. After finishing the transaction there shows a dashed line  I need to hide the dashed line at the finishing of the whole transaction. That means at the end of the final transaction I need to hide the line but it shows a dashed line. Please help me with this

Comment: Please close this question and use a new thread to start a new question.